# How to change input from Object to Collection

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I have been having a great time playing with Felipe Del Rio's procedural building demo file, but have hit something I don't understand.

When I go into the Geometry Nodes>Window Instances, I see the GeoNodes modifier inputs (which are available in the modifier properties tab) wired to their respective "point instance" nodes.

I can switch from an object to a collection inside the Window Instances module, and select a collection there--but when I go back to the modifier inputs (visible in the modifier properties tab) I am only able to select an object, not a collection.

Does anyone know if there is a way to change the type of input in the Modifier properties tab?[image: shows modifier property inputs not matching "collection" vs. "object"]

Comment: Internally it's not the same node socket and data type so you can't have the same Group input linked to both Object and Collection inputs. V3.00 (still in alpha) introduces a Switch node that you can use to switch between two different geometries but it also means you'll have at least one useless input and a superfluous on/off input just to switch between the two. More to the point, you'll have to recreate an input by dragging from the last empty socket of the group input node to the collection input to initialize a propper Collection input in the modifier UI

Comment: Also dynamic type change is in the works (no ETA) https://developer.blender.org/T87049